# Merkwürdiger Gebrauch von »miteinander«

Tags: word-usage, regional

Unter dem Titel [»Schön, Sie nicht kennenzulernen!«](https://www.deutschlandfunkkultur.de/unbekannte-bekannte-schoen-sie-nicht-kennenzulernen.3720.de.html?dram:article_id=428596) bietet der Deutschlandfunk aktuell den Abruf eines Features über unbekannte Bekannte an. Das sind Leute, die man (z. B. im »Pendler-Elend«, wie es heißt) immer wieder sieht, ohne je mit Ihnen Kontakt aufzunehmen. Zu den Mitwirkenden gehören:

- Mr. Outfit
- ein Hardcore-Christ
- der Barock-Engel

Jedenfalls sagt der Autor an Stelle 14:38 mit einer Selbstverständlichkeit, die ihresgleichen sucht:

> ... und keiner redet miteinander.

Das ist mir so noch nicht begegnet. Soll wohl »... und keiner redet mit jemandem« bedeuten.

Ist das ein Regionalismus? Oder ist es einfach nur falsch?

<kbd>abstruse Ausdrucksweise</kbd>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jemand, der ganz allein ist, kann nicht *miteinander reden*. Dazu braucht es mindestens noch eine zusätzliche zweite Person.

Die Tätigkeit *»miteinander reden«* kann also nur von mehreren Personen ausgeübt werden. Das betrifft alle Tätigkeiten, die man *miteinander* macht. Das Adverb *miteinander* zwingt daher dem Subjekt den Plural auf.

Das bedeutet aber auch, dass das Subjekt nicht im Singular stehen kann, wenn das Adverb *miteinander* das Verb modifiziert.

> falsch: Erwin redet miteinander.
>   richtig: Die Gäste reden miteinander.

Nun steht da aber das Indefinitpronomen *keiner* im gegenständlichen Satz im Singular, was man unter anderem auch am Verb sehen kann (»redet« statt »reden«).

Daher:

> falsch: Keiner redet miteinander.

Auflösen kann man das am einfachsten, indem man *miteinander* durch etwas anderes ersetzt, z.B.:

> richtig: Keiner redet mit anderen.

Comment: Eigentlich ist das Hauptproblem der semantischen Logik hier, dass *miteinander* eine Mehrzahl von Leuten benötigt, *keiner* aber als Singular begriffen wird. (Obwohl das ja auch nicht wirklich logisch ist: wie kann *keiner* Einzahl sein? *Keiner* müsste Nullzahl sein.) Eine bessere Lösung als "Keiner redet mit anderen" wäre wohl **"Die Leute reden nicht miteinander."**

Comment: Deutsch hat nur zwei Numeri, nämlich Einzahl und Mehrzahl. Und wenn das Subject selbst nicht in dieses Schema passt (das passiert eigentlich nur bei Indefinitpronomen), dann hilft es - wie in der Antwort ohne hin erwähnt -  auf den Numerus des Verbs zu schauen.

Comment: Diese Antwort geht davon aus, dass der garammatikalische Singular des Subjekts impliziert, dass ein einzelner Akteur (bzw. viele einzelne Akteure, die jeweils einzeln betrachtet werden) gemeint ist. Ich bin nicht sicher, ob das eine valide Annahme ist; es wäre aber eventuell eine separate Frage wert.

Comment: *Keiner* ist nicht per se Singular, sonder ein Indefinitpronomen, das sich auf die Anzahl "Null" bezieht. Logisch ist *Null* nichts, also weder Ein- noch Mehrzahl. Gramatisch kann *Keiner* aber sowohl Singular als auch Plural sein.

Comment: @scieneponder  Kannst du ein Beispiel geben für eine Verwendung von *keiner* in der Mehrzahl?

Comment: @scienceponder: Weißt du ein Beispiel, bei dem _»keiner«_ grammatikalisch für Plural steht? (Christian Geiselmann hat sich bei deinem Namen vertippt)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Sagst du, indem du die Falschheit des Ausdrucks nachweist, gleichzeitig, dass es kein Regionalismus ist? Ungrammatische Regionalismen gibt es nämlich, z. B. in Berlin: _»Ick lieb dir.«_

Comment: @Pollitzer: Nein, ich habe in meiner Antwort nichts über Regionalismen gesagt. Aber ich sage jetzt etwas über Dialekte: Jeder Dialekt hat seine eigene Grammatik, die von der der Standardsprache teilweise erheblich abweichen kann. Daher ist der Ausdruck »Ick lieb dir« ausdrücklich ***nicht*** ungrammatisch, wenn man die Grammatik eines Berliner Dialekts zugrunde legt. Wenn du für die Bewertung eines Satzes der Sprache A die Grammatik der Sprache B verwendest, wirst du natürlich zu falschen Ergebnissen kommen. Du kannst ja auch nicht z.B. englische Sätze mit deutscher Grammatik bewerten.

Comment: Das Abstruse des Ausdrucks erscheint vielleicht etwas stärker, wenn man _»keiner«_ durch _»kein Einziger«_ ersetzt: _»... und kein Einziger redet miteinander.«_ Als ob einer allein das könnte.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn ich so über Beispiele nachdenke, tendiere ich dazu meine Aussage zu revidieren. Grammatisch steht keiner immer im Singular, obwohl klar ist, dass logisch eine vielzahl gemeint ist. Keiner will arbeiten, keiner hat geholfen, etc.

Answer (score 13):

Ich weiß nicht, ob es ein Regionalismus ist, aber

1) Ich habe die Radiosendung live gehört (war es nicht ein "Feature"?), und sie war phänomenal gut. Echte Radiokunst. Und wenn man sie weniger als Journalismus und mehr als Kunst betrachtet, wird man bei der Beurteilung von Ausdrucksformen auch nochmals eine andere Elle anlegen.

2) Für mich ist

> miteinander reden

kein Regionalismus. Man sagt deutschsprachraumweit

> Wir müssen mal miteinander reden

(selten folgt ein angenehmes Gespräch), und somit müsste auch irregional

> nicht miteinander reden

möglich sein, und somit auch

> keiner redet miteinander

Ich gebe aber zu, dass mein Blick auf regionale und überregionale Sprachformen geprägt ist durch eine unvermeidbare Regionalität meines Aufgewachsenseins (in Süddeutschland), wenn auch dann gemildert durch eine ausgeprägte Überregionalität meines weiteren Lebenswandels.

Ich gebe weiter zu, dass "keiner redet miteinander" logikseitig einen Schluckauf hat, denn wenn keiner redet, kann es ja nicht miteinander sein. Insofern ist der Ausdruck vielleicht etwas tautologisch. Auf jeden Fall ist er eher umgangs- als formalsprachlich.

Das Problem lässt sich wohl nicht lösen, nur umschiffen. Zum Beispiel mit:

> Die Leute reden nicht miteinander.

Der umgangssprachliche Ausdruck *keiner redet miteinander* ist in seiner inneren Widersprüchlichkeit übrigens vergleichbar der Aufforderung:

> Wir brauchen hier Platz für mehr Leute. Rückt mal weiter zusammen!

Was denn nun? Weiter? Oder zusammen? Das ist ja eigentlich auch ein Widerspruch. Konsequent wäre, es hieße "enger zusammen".

Nun für die Praxis: In der Zeitung würde ich "keiner redet miteinander" nicht schreiben. Hiermit wären wir wieder bei Punkt 1, siehe oben.

[Haha! Der Leser befindet sich nun in einer Endlosschleife, in der er unweigerlich verhungern muss.]

Comment: Ich sehe das auch so. Keiner redet mit keinem, also redet keiner miteinander. Passt von meinem Sprachgefühl her.

Comment: Auch ich -aus dem Süddeutschen Sprachraum- empfinde "keiner redet miteinander" als absolut in Ordnung und zähle das so zu meinem eigenen Wortschatz und dem Wortschatz meiner Umgebung: ich habe das schon ziemlich oft gehört und selbst benutzt, und mir noch nie Gedanken darüber gemacht.

Comment: "denn wenn keiner redet, kann es ja nicht miteinander sein" - es ist aber genau die Aussage gemeint, dass keiner mit einem anderen redet. Dass der ein oder andere statt dessen vielleicht vor sich hinbrabbelt (sei es mit sich selbst oder mit einem entfernten Gesprächspartner via Smartphone), ist dabei gar nicht ausgeschlossen. Es wird also eventuell durchaus geredet (ob das so ist, darauf wird nicht eingefangen, ist aber für die Aussage auch irrelevant), nur eben nicht *miteinander*.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper  Du hast natürlich recht: Es kann schon sein, dass alle reden, aber nicht miteinander. Aber das ist doch genau der umgekehrte Fall von "keiner redet, also auch nicht miteinander". Wenn keiner redet, redet keiner mit einem anderen, und keiner redet auch nur vor sich hin.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Sicher, aber dass "keiner redet", das behauptet ja überhaupt niemand. Oder anders ausgedrückt: Meinem Verständnis nach beinhaltet die Aussage "Keiner redet miteinander." **nicht** die Aussage "Keiner redet."

Answer (score 0):

> »Keiner redet mit jemandem«

lässt die Möglichkeit offen, dass jemand per Smartphone mit einem Abwesenden redet, im Pendelverkehr nicht unbedingt eine Rarität.

Außerdem lässt es offen, dass jmd. mit sich selbst redet, aber das wäre etwas weit hergeholt.

> ... und keiner redet miteinander

ist da spezifischer. Selbstgespräche kann man nicht wirklich unter *miteinander reden* fassen und ins Telefon zu quaken ist eben auch nicht von *miteinander* erfasst, soweit es sich um die Passagiere eines Verkehrsmittels handelt.

Huberts Antwort:

> Keiner redet mit anderen.

oder

> Keiner redet mit den Anderen.
>
> Keiner redet mit einem Anderen.

würde die Verhältnisse aber korrekt abbilden. Ich denke auch, dass miteinander einen Plural erfordert.

Ein ähnlicher Fall wäre

> Deutsche reden nicht miteinander.

vs.

> Der Deutsche redet nicht miteinander.

Letzteres klingt falsch und ist es m.E. auch.

Comment: "Selbstgespräche kann man wirklich unter miteinander reden fassen" - fehlt hier nicht ein "nicht"?

Comment: Ja, danke. War beim mehrfachen Umformulieren unter den Tisch gefallen.

Comment: Gut, dass ihr miteinander geredet habt!

Answer (score 0):

Für mich klingt es ganz logisch. Ich bin auch der Meinung, dass es in der Sprachpraxis oft genau so gesagt wird. Der Satz hat seine Logik darin, dass "miteinander reden" ein feststehender Begriff ist. "Miteinander reden" bedeutet nicht unbedingt "sprechen", gemeint ist vielmehr der Austausch von Gedanken und Informationen (auch via email).

Praktisches Beispiel: "In der Abteilung X redet keiner miteinander". Das bedeutet nicht, dass keiner den anderen anspricht, oder dass alle schweigen. Es wird auf einen fehlenden Informationsfluss bzw. auf fehlende Absprachen hingewiesen. Was dort keiner macht, ist "miteinander reden". Deshalb erscheint mir das "miteinander" überhaupt nicht unlogisch oder unpassend.